# How to draw an inverse pyramid with asterisks in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce height");

    int height=Integer.parseInt(text);

    drawInversePiramid(height);
}

public static void drawInversePiramid(int height){
    for(int numberasterisks=(height*2)-1,numberspaces=0;numberasterisks>0;numberspaces++,numberasterisks-=2){
        //we draw spaces
        for(int i=0;i<numberspaces;i++){
            System.out.println(" ");
        }//we draw the asterisks
        for(int j=0;j<numberasterisks;j++){
            System.out.println("*");
        }//to jump the line
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

I'm having a trouble compiling the pyramid correctly. Instead it simply prints a vertical pattern with the correct number of asterisks.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is actually correct, except for one minor detail.  You are calling `println` everywhere, which will always print to a newline.  Instead, only call `println` at the end of each line, but use just `print` when you want to build out a given line with stars and spaces.  Using this version of your code:

```
public static void drawInversePiramid(int height) {
    for (int numberasterisks=(height*2)-1,numberspaces=0;numberasterisks>0;numberspaces++,numberasterisks-=2){
        // we draw spaces
        for (int i=0; I < numberspaces; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        // we draw the asterisks
        for (int j=0; j < numberasterisks; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        // to jump the line
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

drawInversePiramid(3);
```

I get the correct output:

```
*****
 ***
  *
```

### Demo